# Flask key error: KeyError: 'HTTP_USEREXECUTIONCONTEXT'

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request to my API (`url` in the below code), via the following:

```
files = [
  ('file', open(os.path.join(path, 'file1.pdf'), mode='rb'))]

userexec = '{"ClientName":"","UserId":1234,"ContactCode":1234,"LoggerCode":"1234","EntityId":2,"EntityType":"","Product":9,"Culture":"en-US","UserName":"","Contexts":[],"CompanyName":"abcd"}'

header = {'id': 'unique1', 'BuyerPartnerCode': '1234', 'userexecutioncontext':userexec}

test_app(url, path, files, header)
```

However, when I'm trying to access the `userexec` header in my API:

```
res = request.headers
userexec = str(res['userexecutioncontext'])
```

I keep getting this error: 
[image]

**Am I missing something here, or am I trying to access the header wrong?**
(PS: All other headers are accessed fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialize the `userexec` when sending in the request maybe try

```py
json.loads(json.dumps(userexec))
```